# Extracting specific option price data from Excels

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am looking for an effective way to extract option price data from Excel spreadsheets with specific criteria: only prices (in separate columns) with traded amount (in other columns) greater than zero should be extracted to another sheet. There are over 5000 option contracts per one spreadsheet so what would be an efficient way to do this by VBA code?
[So for example regarding this snapshot, I would only need values in cells D18, G18 and P18 because corresponding values in E18,H18 and Q18>0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uds83.png)

Comment: Have you tried before asking this question?

Comment: Yes but I don't have the knowledge to create the needed macro so that's where I would need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see which is the trade amount and which is the price, but let's say you want to copy data from one sheet to another if the value is >0.  Modify the script below to suit your needs.  It should be pretty close to what you want.

```
Sub TryMe()

    Dim i As Range
    For Each i In Range("A1:A1000")
        If i.Value > 0 Then
            i.Select
            ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```